# Is the 'Sigma 18-200mm F3.5-6.3 II DC OS HSM' compatible with my D5000, and will it autofocus?

Tags: sigma, compatibility

Is the 'Sigma 18-200mm F3.5-6.3 II DC OS HSM' compatible with my D5000, and will it auto focus?

As seen here:
http://www.digitalrev.com/product/sigma-18-200mm-f3-5/MTMyMzM_A
+
http://www.sigmaphoto.com/shop/18-200mm-f35-63-II-dc-os-hsm-sigma

If so, how would this perform compared with say the 'Nikon AF-S DX NIKKOR 18-200mm f/3.5-5.6G ED VR II' ?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, assuming the Sigma lens you are talking about is designed for Nikon F-mount.

Been a Ultrasonic-type motor (ie/ the **HSM**), the lens "Sigma 18-200mm F3.5-6.3 II DC OS HSM" will be able to focus on all models of Nikon DSLR.

In addition, with F-mount lenses, only the Screw Drive-type motor (ie/ the non- **AF-S** or **AF-I** lenses) requires Nikon camera body to have built-in auto focus motor.

Comment: @Imre Thanks for the correction, the alphabet soup gets a bit twisted.

Answer (score 0):

As rockacola explained, the Sigma lens will be able to focus on your system.

In your question you also wanted to know how the Sigma lens performed compared with the Nikon counterpart.

First let me state that I'm not an expert photographer, and I do not possess either of the stated lenses, but I can tell you that the two lenses should perform in a very similar fashion when your using it fully zoomed in as they will both let in the same ammount of light. The difference between those two lenses resides in the fact that the Nikon will let in more light when use fully zoomed out (F5.6) compared to the Sigma (F6.3). So in theory the Nikon lens would perform better in situations when there is less light, perhaps interior photography.

Hope this helps!